# Possible to reference front-matter values in template files?

Tags: youtube, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I have a theme and for a post page, I'm showing the `image` value if there is one.

I also have a plugin that renders a YouTube video and usage is like this: `{% youtube id_12345 %}`.

In my template file, would it be possible to reference the `video` value from the front-matter of a post and render it with the same plugin that I can use in my content?

Something like:

```
{% if post.video %}
  {% youtube {{post.video}} %}    # <-- this does not work
{% elsif post.image %}
  <img src="{{ post.image }}" class="post-image" alt="{{ post.title }}">
{% endif %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: (I've deleted my other reply, as the whole `capture` approach shouldn't even be necessary in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

Since variables are not compatible with `{% %}` calls, I ended up reproducing much of the plugin's functionality in this one line. I started with the [BetterTube](https://github.com/tuananh/BetterTube) and modified it for my needs.

```
{% if post.video %}
  {% capture video_id %}{{ post.video | 
        replace: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','' | 
        replace: 'https://youtu.be/', '' }}{% endcapture %}
  <figure class='BetterTube' data-youtube-id='{{video_id}}' data-player-width='' 
  data-player-height='' id='{{video_id}}' style='padding-bottom: 56.25%'>
  <a class='BetterTubePlayer' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{video_id}}' 
  style='background: url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{video_id}}/hqdefault.jpg) 50% 
  50% no-repeat rgb(0, 0, 0);'></a><div class='BetterTube-playBtn'></div>&nbsp;
  </figure>
{% elsif post.image %}
  <img src="{{ post.image }}" class="post-image" alt="{{ post.title }}">
{% endif %}
```

I wished I could simply call the plugin, but sadly I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you're using [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/joelverhagen/1805814). I don't know much about writing plugins, but it seems to me like you can't use variables in it.

Maybe try [this one](https://gist.github.com/vanto/1455726) instead? It seems like it [supports variables](https://gist.github.com/vanto/1455726#gistcomment-345615).

That being said, I don't even think you need to go through the hassle of running a plugin for that. The following code should do the work just fine:

```
{% if post.video %}
  <iframe width="560" height="420" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ post.video }}?color=white&theme=light"></iframe>
{% elsif post.image %}
  <img src="{{ post.image }}" class="post-image" alt="{{ post.title }}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes and no. :) I used a similar plugin but I modified it to display a figure and when clicking on the placeholder, it loads the video (much faster page loads like this).